# Token category of the ellipsis

Tags: c++, token, lexical-analysis, ellipsis

Which is the token category of the ellipsis (`...`) in the C++ programming language after tokenization? I can't seem to find anything specifying whether it is a delimiter, and operator, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipsis is described in the grammatical description of *parameter-declaration-clause* in C++11, 8.3.5/3.

C++ doesn't have a complete and exhaustive formal grammar, so I don't believe it makes sense to ask for a "token class": Nobody ever claimed that C++ *has* token classes. A C++ program is well-formed if it conforms to the rules laid out in the standard.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Moreover, with variadic macros and variadic templates, it may have different "classes" depending where it is. I really apreciate the global explanation about C++. Thanks for the answer! :)